# Хочу переделать скрипт добавляющий определенные символы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю скрипт на jquery, который должен добавлять к определенному символу/словосочетанию/цифрам также определенные символы/словосочетания/цифры. Например в поле textarea пишем "123" и в реальном времени добавляется "456" без пробела. Или например вводим "соба", где без пробела должен добавляться слог "ка". При этом важно, чтобы слог, который добавлялся бы не был виден в самом окне textarea, для этого требуется прямо в строчке в коде установить style (fonts-size:0px;), сам текст с добавленными символами будет виден уже после отправки в условном письме или комментарии. А также возможность составить некую базу из подобных слов прямо в коде строчка за строчкой, другими словами добавлять от 10+ символов/слов/цифр/ для добавления. За основу я взял скрипт по замене символов, но он к сожалению не выполняет всех нужных задач. Не работает если установлено более одной строчки со словом для замены. Не добавляет, а заменяет символы. И нет возможности установить (fonts-size:0px;) к слову, которое добавляется к символу.

```
<textarea></textarea>

$("textarea").on('keyup', function() {
  let value = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(value.replace('123', '456'));
  $(this).val(value.replace('соба', 'ка'));
  $(this).val(value.replace('свобо', 'да'));
  //и так далее..
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```js
let rep = [ // Некий словарь
  ['123', '456'], // [слово, окончание]
  ['соба', 'ка'],
  ['свобо', 'да'],
  ['\\*S77', '#G228'] // !!! экранируйте символы двойным обратным слешем (\\) !!!
];
    
$('#message').on('keyup', function(){
  let text = $(this).val(); // Берём весь текст из textarea #message
  for(let i = 0; i < rep.length; i++) { // Проходим циклом по словарю
    let reg = new RegExp('(^|\\s|\\W)'+rep[i][0]+'(\\s|\\W|$)', 'gm'); // Создаём регулярное выражение
    text = text.replace(reg, '$1'+rep[i][1]+'$2'); // Заменяем первое слово из словоря, на слово+окончание
  }
  $('#replace').val(text); // Добавляем новый текст в отдельный textarea replace
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<textarea id="replace"></textarea>
```

Comment: По работоспособности скрипта все именно так, только можно, чтобы добавление текста во втором textarea (replace) происходило сразу же, а не после разфокуса первого окна (message)? А также позвольте второй дополнительный небольшой вопрос. Возможно ли, чтобы во втором textarea (replace) первая часть слова наоборот не писалась, а оставалось только окончание из словаря?

Comment: @Magman, исправил ответ

Comment: благодарю вас за помощь!

Comment: подскажите, как поправить, чтобы если появится слово в словаре '123соба', считалось бы как за отдельное, а не как за '123' ? Так как если мы напишем '123соба', то замена произойдет на символы '123'. А также объясните пожалуйста, почему если в словаре, слово начинается с символа '*' например '*S77' , то словарь перестает работать, но кода мы убираем из словаря эту строку, то скрипт работает хорошо..

Comment: @Magman, добавил условие, что перед и после слова может что-то находится (пробел, перенос строки, знаки препинания или ничего), а для того, чтобы использовать символы, нужно экранировать символ - двумя обратными слешами `\\`.